# How do I get groups from AAD using Powershell Function App?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-function-app

I want to get all users from certain groups in AAD using Powershell with a Function app, but I keep getting permission errors and I don't know how to assign them.

```
$groupsAD = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
      $groupsAD.Add('Group1')
      $groupsAD.Add('Group2')

foreach ($groupAD in $groupsAD) {
    $group = Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName $groupAD
    # further code

}
```

The error:

> [Error] ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the
> operation.Exception             :Type    : System.ExceptionMessage :
> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.HResult :
> -2146233088CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-AzADGroup], ExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId :
> Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.GetAzureADGroupCommandInvocationInfo
> :MyCommand        : Get-AzADGroupScriptLineNumber : 16OffsetInLine
> : 14HistoryId        : 1ScriptName       :
> C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1Line             : $group =
> Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName $groupADPositionMessage  : At
> C:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger\run.ps1:16 char:14+     $group =
> Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName $groupAD

When creating this function locally it works fine after I authenticate with Connect-AzAccount.
Also tried to create an identity and authenticate it with it, but as far as I know it's for Azure resources not AAD.

Comment: May I know how did you do authentication in your function with `Connect-AzAccount` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, here provide two solutions for your reference:

**1.** If you use username/password to do authentication in `Connect-AzAccount` command, you need to make sure the user account has required permission for get AD group. Then use the code below in your function:

```
$User = "{username}"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "{password}" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential

$group = Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName "{group name}"
```

**2.** If you do not want to use username/password to do authentication in your function. You can use service principal to do it.

First you need to [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application) an app in your Azure AD, I registered an app named "**huryGetToken6**" in my Azure AD.

Then click "**Certificates & secrets**" tab, new client secret. Copy the client secret to your notepad.
[image]

Then add the permission to the registered app, do it with the steps in below screenshots.
[image]

[image]

Please do not forget click "**Grant admin consent for xxx**" after add the permissions to registered app.

After that, you can use the code below in your function to get AD group:

```
$username = "{client id/application id}"
$password = "{client secret}"
$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $secureStringPwd
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant "{tenant id}" -ServicePrincipal

$group = Get-AzADGroup -DisplayName "huryGroup"
```

For the params in above commands, you can find the client id/application id and tenant id on the "**Overview**" page of your registered app.
[image]